# How can I prevent my computer from crashing when running R-script on large dataset

Tags: r, image, imagemagick, purrr

- **Goal**: Read, compress and write images from one location to another.
  The image dataset is about 5 TB in size. The average size of the individual images is about 2-5 Mb.
- **Problem**: When I run it for
  the whole dataset, my Mac crashes after about 1 GB. The script works
  for a subset of about 400 images.

By reading in the images one by one, I had hoped it would not require too much memory and processing power, but I probably missed something. Could some review my code below and provide insight in why it crashes?  Any tips and suggestions would be very much appreciated. Apologies for not giving a reproducible example.

```
rm(list=ls())

## 1. LOAD PACKAGES
library(magick)
library(purrr)
library(furrr)

## 2. SET MAIN FOLDER
Directory_Folder <- "C:/Users/Nick/Downloads/" 
Folder_Name <- "Photos for Nick"

## 3. SET NEW LOCATION
New_Directory <- "C:/Users/Daikoro/Desktop/"     ## MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE FINAL FORWARD SLASH

## 4. LIST ALL FILES
list.of.files <- list.files(path = paste0(Directory_Folder, Folder_Name), full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

## 5. FUNCTION FOR READING, RESIZING, AND WRITING IMAGES
MyFun <- function(i) {
  
  new.file.name <- gsub(Directory_Folder, New_Directory, i)
  
  magick::image_read(i) %>%  ## IMPORT PHOTOS INTO R
            image_scale("400") %>%  ## IMAGE RE-SCALING
            image_write(path = new.file.name)
}

## 6. SET UP MULTI-CORES
future::plan(multiprocess)

## 7. RUN FUNCTION ON ALL FILES
future_map(list.of.files, MyFun)   ## THIS WILL TAKE A WHILE...AND CRASHES AT 1GB
```

Comment: how many cores are you using?

Comment: Ah, I didn't specify that, but I assumed that the 'future::plan(multiprocess)' would evaluate and set the appropriate number of cores.

Comment: my point is that multiprocess is not shared-memory, so you might be exhausting memory by trying to run more jobs in parallel than you have memory for ... ?

Comment: ... and while `multiprocess` has sane defaults ... trusting that it will know what you are planning on doing and giving you the appropriate number of processes is really a recipe for problem. I think you're bringing this on yourself. BTW: since all you're doing is scaling all images, it is likely much easier to do this with the `magick.exe` command-line utility (not included in R's `magick` package), as I suspect there is no need to read the images into memory in R.

Comment: For instance, if you are in a console in the directory with source images, then you can `mkdir sm ; ls *jpg | xargs -P 4 -IZ  magick convert Z -resize 300 sm/Z` for resizing four images at a time in parallel. Up the `-P` number if you want to take it up a notch. I don't think R's `magick` package can be any faster than this method, and even if the author took many cautions, I would not be surprised if the R implementation were a "bit" slower (untested).

Comment: What is the maximum image size, how many workers are you using according to `nbrOfWorkers()`? Does `nbrOfWorkers()*MaxImageSize` fit in memory?

Comment: I don't know the maximum image size, but the average is about 2-5 Mb.
`nbrOfWorkers() = 1`

Comment: Edit your ImageMagick policy.xml file to change your resources. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive and https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php https://imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel

Comment: Thanks, it's not that the images themselves are large, I just many many images of 2-5 Mb each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the feedback from Ben Bolker, r2evans, and Waldi  I managed to get the script going. I added `gc()` in the last line of `MyFun`. And also specified a number of cores like this:

```
## SET UP MULTI-CORES
no_cores <- availableCores() - 1
future::plan(multisession, workers = no_cores)
```

While this made the script much slower, at least it didn't crash. I'm not sure if that's because I more processing cores were available, or because of the `gc()` line.